# using ANT to automatic run JUNIT cases, setting up dependencies

Tags: java, testing, ant, junit

I have the following setup for my application:

[image]

The `project TestAll` currently contain a java file that run all the TestAll javafiles in all my other projects and this works as expected. The problem im facing is that I want this `TestAll.java` to be run from a ant script and have it record the result in a report file. This javafile is dependent on all the other projects in my application.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Ant-Test" default="main" basedir=".">
  <!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
  <property name="src.dir" location="" />
  <property name="build.dir" location="../bin" />
  <property name="dist.dir" location="../dist" />
  <property name="lib.dir" location="../lib" /> 
  <property name="test.dir" location="../src" />
  <property name="test.report.dir" location="../testreport" />


  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
  </target>

      <!-- Define the classpath which includes the junit.jar and the classes after compiling-->
      <path id="junit.class.path">
        <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/junit.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${build.dir}" />
      </path>

  <target name="makedir">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${test.report.dir}" />
  </target>

  <!-- Compiles the java code (including the usage of library for JUnit -->
      <target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
          <classpath refid="junit.class.path" />
        </javac>
  </target>

      <target name="junit" depends="compile">
        <junit printsummary="on" fork="true" haltonfailure="yes">
          <classpath refid="junit.class.path" />
          <formatter type="xml" />
          <batchtest todir="${test.report.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
              <include name="**/*Test*.java" />
            </fileset>
          </batchtest>
        </junit>
      </target>

  <!--Creates the deployable jar file  -->
  <target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\se.testall.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="test.Main" />
      </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>

  <target name="main" depends="compile, jar, junit">
    <description>Main target</description>
  </target>

</project>
```

And the errors im getting is:

```
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Repositories\MyProject\TestAllProjects\bin
[javac] C:\Repositories\MyProject\TestAllProjects\src\se\testall\src\TestAllClass.java:6: error: package se.tlv.AProject.testall does not exist
[javac] import se.tlv.AnotherProject.testall.*;
[javac] ^
[javac] C:\Repositories\TestAllProjects\src\se\src\TestAllClass.java:7: error: package se.AnotherProject.testall does not exist
```

..and so on for all the internal imports in my `TestAll project`

This is most likley a classpath error where ANT in unable to find the files it needs, but I have no idea how to resolve it and have been trying for almost a full day. Any help is appreciated

Comment: +1 for well presented question.

Answer (score 1):

The classpath provided to the javac task is: the junit jar, the build directory and the current directory.

Unless the current directory (where build.xml is located) is `se`, the javac task won't be able to find any java files to compile them.

Given that, the classpath for the javac task will need to include a path to each `se` directory in each project.

Edit:

Note: Unless you're planning on packaging the tests with the rest of the code, you should have two javac tasks that build to a build directory and a test build directory, then provide a path to each of those to junit so it can run the tests, but provide only the build directory path to the jar task.